# php variable not working within else function

Tags: php, sql, variables

So I'm using sql with php but one variable doesn't work. The variable *$pagina* works in the *$sql* but not within the *else {} ($sql2 and header)*. The other variables do work *($naam and $bericht)*. Can anyone spot the mistake?
(Sorry for any possible mistakes in my English.)

```
<?php
$bericht = $_POST ['bericht'];
$pagina = $_GET ['id'];
$naam = $_SESSION['login'];
$con = mysqli_connect("host","sql","pw","sql");

if (empty($bericht)) {
}
    else
    {
$sql2="INSERT INTO Comments (bericht_id, naam, bericht) VALUES ('$pagina', '$naam', '$bericht')";
mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
header("location:directbericht.php?id=$pagina");
    }

$sql="SELECT * FROM Berichten WHERE id = $pagina";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  while ($obj=mysqli_fetch_object($result))
    {
    echo $obj->naam;
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo $obj->bericht;
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo $obj->datum;
    echo "<br><br>";
    }
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM Comments WHERE bericht_id = $pagina ORDER BY id ASC";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  while ($obj=mysqli_fetch_object($result))
    {
        echo "<tr><td><font color='white'>";
    echo $obj->naam;
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo $obj->bericht;
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo $obj->datum;
    echo "<br><br>";
        echo "</font></tr></td>";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because of the `font` tag or maybe the problem with quotes in the value causing an SQL injection, or that one value is GET and one is POST. No it's definitely the font tag..

Comment: You mean redirect in else is not working? Add exit(); after header redirect. also use absolute path if required.

Comment: First of all start binding sql params because currently your code is sql injection vulnerability. Read first answer in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php.

Comment: Yes and the insert is also not working, when I put a number after the "$pagina =" it does work but it doesn't work with the <i>$_GET['id'];</i>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple major things wrong with your code.

The first, and most important to deal with is how you're inserting data into the database. As it is currently written, you are vulnerable to a [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack. Please read on how to use mysqli's [bind parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), or better yet, upgrade to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Secondly, you're trying to pull data using both `$_POST[]` and `$_GET[]` in the same logic path. An http connection will be either a *post*, *get*, or some other kind of request. It will **never** be both. This is likely why it works when you put a number in, but not when you try to use `$_GET[]`.